# When I send JWT, I received a JWT in blank

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

All working, except the JWT Issuer/Sender, I analyzed the AppInsights at least 10 times and nothing:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information to facilitate our testing.

Comment: Did you select id token under **Implicit grant** in Azure AD app? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga#register-a-web-application. "Under Implicit grant, select both the Access tokens and ID tokens check boxes."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this GitHub thread around same issue - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/issues/24

It seems something is missing for which you can visit [Request an access token in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens) and validate.

Moreover, one of the probable reasons for this is a missing Read scope. Once your app is created, open the app's **Published Scopes** blade and create a scope with `read` name.

Comment: More one question... Can I know what step I'm? Because... I'm adding a InputClaim named Step and setting DefaultValue="StepOne" and AlwaysUseDefaultValue always, but this is so frustating...

Comment: There is a easily way to do this?

Comment: What is the issue? Can u elaborate? Also, did this response answer your question?

Comment: This response answered my question. My issue is recognize what OrchestationStep I'm inside Javascript for customize many things in UI. I usually use Claim Step to get Step in Javascript side.